# What is the user BUILTIN (BUILTIN)?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

We have 2 folders in our local E: that have the user BUILTIN (BUILTIN) assigned with full permission.

How could we find this user?

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::E:\OT\Test
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : OTTESTSERVER\None
Access : S-1-5-32 Allow  FullControl
         S-1-5-32 Allow  268697600
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         CREATOR OWNER Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
```

How can we add this user into the security tab?
We are not able to find this user?

[image: Link to screen capture]

Answer (score 0):

"BUILTIN" means the SID is deterministic and well-known. For example, the BUILTIN\Administrators group SID is always S-1-5-32-544.  To grant permissions to one of the BUILTIN security principals, you need to select Object Types, and ensure that the Built-in Security Principals box is checked.  If you are using a command line utility such as ICACLS, you may also specify the SID if known.

[image: Built-in Security Principals checkbox]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers#well-known-sids